# Splittable Panel

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I try to make a reusable Horizontal splittable panel in GXT 3.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868934/how-to-split-a-panel-in-ext-gwt). I adapted with sencha.gxt imports and I came up with this solution :

```
public class WestCenter extends BorderLayoutContainer {

  private ContentPanel westPanel;
  private ContentPanel centerPanel;

  public WestCenter(){
    westPanel = new ContentPanel();
    centerPanel = new ContentPanel();

    BorderLayoutData westData=new BorderLayoutData(800);
    westData.setSplit(true);
    westData.setCollapsible(true);
    westData.setMargins(new Margins(0,5,0,0));

    BorderLayoutData centerData=new BorderLayoutData();
    setWestWidget(westPanel, westData);
    setCenterWidget(centerPanel,centerData);
  }

  public void setWestHeadingText(String text){
    this.westPanel.setHeadingText(text);
  }

  public void setCenterHeadingText(String text){
    this.centerPanel.setHeadingText(text);
  }

  @UiChild(tagname = "westContent")
  public void setWestContent(Widget widget){
    this.westPanel.setWidget(widget);
  }

  @UiChild(tagname = "centerContent")
  public void setCenterContent(Widget widget){
    this.centerPanel.setWidget(widget);
  }
```

**Problem**

I have a very weird behavior : I can drag the split bar from right to left but not from left to right. Hence, the dragging from right to left cannot be undone!

Any ideas?

I tried:

- centerData.setSplit(true)
- centerData.setMargins(new Margins(0,0,0,5))

... without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the javadoc:

`When split = true, it is common to specify a minSize and maxSize for the region.`

The default values for `minSize` and `maxSize` were actually far too small.